# Is there a way to list Sucker Punch jobs on queue from rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sucker-punch

In DelayedJob we can use `Delayed::Job.all` on console to list all jobs on queue.
Is there a way to do the same using SuckerPunch gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SuckerPunch everything runs in-process, so there is no external job queue backed by a database or other data store that can be queried from a separate process.

The only way I can think of to achieve what you want is to attach to the running Ruby process via a debug session and examine memory to dump out the information you want.

Based on my knowledge of SuckerPunch, if examining the jobs from the console or other process is a feature you need, you will have to switch to some other background job framework.

Answer (score 5):

To get some info regarding queues you can also use `SuckerPunch::Queue.stats` or `SuckerPunch::Queue.all` from rails console.

Comment: This answer didn't help me, but it was useful info:   {"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SuckerPunchAdapter::JobWrapper"=>
  {"workers"=>{"total"=>1, "busy"=>0, "idle"=>1}, "jobs"=>{"processed"=>2, "failed"=>0, "enqueued"=>0}}}